# How to get list of available attributes using ActiveRecord enum Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Let I have a simple model called Fruit, and Fruit's instance has field fruit_name as a string.

```
class Fruit < ApplicationRecord
  enum fruit_name: {
    banana: 'banana',
    apple:  'apple'
  }
end
```

Is there a simple way to get access to enum list? Searching for something like this:

```
  Fruit.allowed_attributes_for(:fruit_name)
  => ['banana', 'apple']
```

Comment: `Fruit.fruit_names`, not?

Comment: Yes, definitely that

Comment: Yes, thanks, It works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Fruit.fruit_names
```

This will give you a ruby hash of the fruit names. Also your enum is wrong.

```
enum fruit_names: { banana: 0, apple: 1}
```

Enums are stored as an integer in the database so be careful with them. They are fantastic. You can also call:

```
Fruit.banana
```

That will return all the bananas objects.